# vba quarterly returns

Tags: excel, vba, finance

Can anybody tell me a VBA Function or button that would calculate quarterly returns only on a quarterly basis (i.e., first quarter return is based on January till March returns) without overlapping observations.

The function that I'm using now is just the AVERAGE of, for example, returns from January until March, but the actual calculation cell is in April.

An example of what I'm asking is in the picture link. I would like the function to run for the time period that I choose.

[image]

Thank you very much!

edit: I'm asking for help with the code because I'm new to vba so I cannot do it yet on my own.

edit2: The code that I adapted from class is this:

```
 Option Explicit

 Public Sub QuarterReturns()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("B2")
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    n = rng.End(x2Down).Column - rng.Row + 1
    Set rng = rng.Resize(n, 1)

    Dim returns As Variant
    returns = rng.Value2

    Dim quarter As Variant

    ReDim quarter(1 To n - 1, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To n - 1
        ror(i, 1) = prices(i + 1, 1) / prices(i, 1) - 2#
    Next i
    rng.Offset(1, 2).Resize(n - 1, 2).Value2 = quarter
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you looking for someone to write you the VBA code?  Or are you asking if there's an existing function that does what you want?

Comment: What date format is that? `YYDDMM`?

Comment: @Kevin I'm sorry if I didn't explain it properly. I am asking for help with the code because I'm new to vba so I cannot do it yet on my own.

Comment: @BruceWayne It is YYMM

Comment: You should at least *start* it on your own, show your code, and discuss problems that you are having with it. As it is, your question seems like a request for others to write the code for you, which isn't how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Don't always think VBA is the answer. You can do this with a Pivot table, because you can select dates by Quarter (you'll just need to convert your dates into actual dates

Comment: @JohnColeman Sorry, I didn't know that I needed to do this. I started off with this code that I saw in class but it's not working properly. The code is in the edit

Comment: I gave an answer that will hopefully help you out (though it doesn't do it in VBA.)  To be honest, I do a *LOT* of misc analysis/calculation/data-playing in Excel, and I think its ability to work through data analysis is very underrated (last two things I used it for were calculating belt capacities for Factorio and water usage in OxygenNotIncluded.)  If you're doing freehand calculations, you can usually get the answer faster than simply doing the math on paper, and both faster/easier than actually coding a solution.  Loves me some Excel  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the first point: StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service.  Asking us, "Hey, can someone write me something that does X?" is likely to get you ridiculed/scolded/etc.

That said, I'm going to help you with two building-blocks that might help you get to the finish line on your own.

Prereq: VBA is overused within Excel.  Excel has amazingly powerful abilities just within the formulas.  In this case, you can actually get what you want with zero code, and only one additional (calculated) column.  The reason this is probably a better solution is because Excel docs with VBA macros tend to be disabled (for *very* good reason) and it becomes a lot harder to see what's being done behind the scenes.  With a calculated column, someone interested in digging behind the numbers can easily see what's going on without having to delve into code.

**Building Block #1: Year and Month functions.**

If you've got a date column (which you don't right now - you need to change that column to something that actually represents a date object), you can actually get the Quarter by assembling something like:

```
=YEAR(A1)&"-Q"&((MONTH(A1)+2)/3)
```

Basically, the YEAR() function gets the year, and the MONTH() function gets the month number.  From there, I just use some basic math and string-combining to get a result like:

> 2018-Q2

**Building Block #2 - CountIf/SumIf/AverageIf**

Excel has some really great xxxIf() functions, that will get the average/sum/count/etc for a range, *but only for the values that meet a certain criteria.*

So in your case, if you Sum of all the 2018-Q2 records, you simply use the SUMIF() function to add up all the values, where the entry equals '2018-Q2'.

Hope that helps you out on your task.  If not, I'd actually encourage you to break the problem down into smaller subtasks, google those subtasks - and if you can't find anything for a specific task, ask a question about *just* that part.  Asking, "Hey, how do I sum three cells in VBA?" goes over a lot better than "Hey, write this function for me"  :-)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, that is indeed helpful. The only problem is that I really need it in vba, so is there any way that you could help me with my code?

Comment: Well, the last paragraph is what you want, then.  Break the task down into as small of components/tasks/elements as you can.  If you know how to do one of those, great!  If not, google it.  If you somehow find a portion of the problem that *hasn't* got an answer (to be honest, its pretty doubtful) then go ahead and ask that specific question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: By the way, that's generally how you need to approach programming.  Don't think of it as "I need to write a program that does XYZ."  Instead, think, "To accomplish XYZ, I'll need to first do A, then either B or C, finishing up with D and E.  So, how do I do A?"  The smaller you can break apart your tasks, the better you'll find yourself doing.